# How to merge these two lists?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Models:

```
public class DogOwner
{
    public int OwnerId {get;set;}
    public List<Dog> Dogs {get;set;}
}
```

and

```
public class CatOwner
{
    public int OwnerId {get;set;}
    public List<Cat> Cats {get;set;}
}
```

So I've got List and List and want to merge them into List of Owners where Owner is:

```
public class Owner
{
   public int OwnerId {get;set;}
   public int DogsCount {get;set}
   public int CatsCount {get;set;}
}
```

For example if input data is:

```
List<DogOwner>:
DogOwner Id=1 with 3 dogs
DogOwner Id=2 with 2 dogs

List<CatOwner>
CatOwner Id=5 with 2 cats
CatOwner Id=2 with 1 cat
```

Result should be:

```
List<Owner>
Owner Id=1 CatsCount = 0, DogsCount=3
Owner Id=2 CatsCount = 1, DogsCount=2
Owner Id=5 CatsCount = 2, DogsCount=0
```

How can I accomplish it? :)

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Yes. using `Select` and `Concat` I can get a list with `Owner Id=2 CatsCount=1 DogsCount=0` and `Owner Id=2 CatsCount=0 DogsCount=2` but it is not what I want. Can you please help me?

Comment: Once you do `Select` and `Concat`, continue with `GroupBy`.

Comment: @Elekk do you know what polymorphism is? Are you a beginner in programming or do you just have no knowledge of linq?

Comment: @Mafii I just have no knowledge of linq yet...

Comment: @Elekk Check the solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Linq` you could do this.

First `Concat` both the lists and then `GroupBy` on `OwnerId` to get cat/dog count.

```
var results = dogowners.Select(x=> new Owner()                               
                            {
                                OwnerId = x.OwnerId, 
                                DogsCount = x.Dogs.Count()
                            })
                        .Concat(catowners.Select(x=> new Owner() 
                            {
                                OwnerId = x.OwnerId, 
                                CatsCount = x.Cats.Count()
                            }))
                        .GroupBy(x=> x.OwnerId)
                        .Select(x=> new Owner() 
                        {
                            OwnerId = x.Key, 
                            DogsCount = x.Sum(s=>s.DogsCount),  
                            CatsCount = x.Sum(s=>s.CatsCount)
                        }) 
                        .ToList();
```

Since you are new, I though non `Linq` solution might help for you.

**Non Linq**

```
    Dictionary<int, Owner> owners = new Dictionary<int, Owner>();
    foreach(var dg in dogowners)
    {

        if(owners.ContainsKey(dg.OwnerId))
        {
            owners[dg.OwnerId].DogsCount += dg.Dogs.Count();
        }
        else 
        {
            owners.Add(dg.OwnerId, new Owner() 
            {
                OwnerId = dg.OwnerId, 
                DogsCount = dg.Dogs.Count()
            });
        }           
    }

    foreach(var ct in catowners)
    {
        if(owners.ContainsKey(ct.OwnerId))
        {
            owners[ct.OwnerId].CatsCount += ct.Cats.Count();
        }
        else 
        {
            owners.Add(ct.OwnerId, new Owner() 
            {
                OwnerId = ct.OwnerId, 
                CatsCount = ct.Cats.Count()
            });
        }           
    }
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KCviN0)

Comment: I can't believe we wrote the exact same solution ! That's crazy. Thumbs up for you.

Comment: Happens some time :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is not pretty, but it works:

**(The key is to transform both DogOwner and CatOwner into Owner)**

```
var results = dogOwners.Select(x => new Owner() { OwnerId = x.OwnerId, DogsCount = x.Dogs.Count })
                        .Union(catOwners.Select(x => new Owner() { OwnerId = x.OwnerId, CatsCount = x.Cats.Count }))
                        .GroupBy(x => x.OwnerId)
                        .Select(x => 
                                new Owner()
                                {
                                    OwnerId = x.Key,
                                    CatsCount = x.Sum(y => y.CatsCount),
                                    DogsCount = x.Sum(y => y.DogsCount)
                                });
```